# How to store a video from WP8/ WP8.1 to Azure Storage?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

It migth be an off topic question since I not putting any code. But, I really need you help to know how could I upload a video recorded from a WP8 or 8.1 app to a Windows Azure Storage.

I've google it for a long time but I couldn't find anything related to it. I have seen how to do it from an Image taken from a mobile app to Azure Storage. But not for a video.

Any help, code, turorial that you can provide me will be very helful.

Thanks in advance

Comment: you mean uploading a video to the storage?

Comment: This should be the same for a video as for an image. Both will go into the same blob storage. What problems are you having following your existing image upload instructions?

Comment: @Kulasangar, yes that rigth.

Comment: @Rob Caplan, that's what I wanted to confirm, whether the code to upload a video is the same as if I upload an image. I'm having some problems with the classes used to process a video rather than a image. Migth be there is something that I'm missing

Comment: Uploading the file will be the same. If you need to do processing on the file then that will be different.

Comment: The code should be the same. Is it possible to share the code and the error you are receiving?

Comment: MikePR--

Any progress here? Looking to solve the exact same problem and I don't see a good answer anywhere else on the Net.

Oddly common scenario that no one's documented.

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to share the code that you used for processing the video that would really help us with answering your question. I'm guessing you're looking at this tutorial http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-windows-store-dotnet-upload-data-blob-storage/?

As the other commenters have mentioned already, you can use the same code for **uploading** videos to Azure Storage.